# Get expanded accordion pane

Tags: asp.net

I am using below code to loop through all the accordion panes, how to get expanded pane so i can update database accordingly.

For Each ap As AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionPane In acc1.Panes
next

i am not getting any status visible property, any help or comment  would be appreciated.

Regards
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property called SelectedIndex use this to get the current expanded pane